# How to unpack three different jsons within a json to create 3 different daatframes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a json string with 3 different data sets nested inside called "data", "ml_count" and "mesh_count".

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "SID": "FIA12344333",
      "MId": "testid",
      "BCode": "testcode",
      "Flag": true,
      "Pcode": "LS29",
      "Lcode": "LFDSelfTest"
    }
  ],
  "ml_count": [
    {
      "Count": 2617,
      "Pcode": "N/A",
      "Lcode": "AP"
    },
    {
      "Count": 2109,
      "Pcode": "N/A",
      "Lcode": "MK"
    },
    {
      "Count": 746,
      "Pcode": "N/A",
      "Lcode": "Randox"
    }
  ],
  "mesh_count": [
    {
      "Count": 1,
      "Pcode": "AS11",
      "Lcode": "LFDSelfTest"
    },
    {
      "Count": 1,
      "Pcode": "LS29",
      "Lcode": "LFDSelfTest"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to create 3 different pandas dataframes for each
I have tried to to normalise json

```
with open(path+r'\json.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
dfs = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(dfs)
```

but this gives me a result like this

```py
    data                                                mlwh_rolling_count    ​    ​    ​    ​    ​    ​    ​      ​​mesh_rolling_count

0   [{'SpecimenID': 'FIA12344333', 'MongoId': 'tes...   [{'RollingCount': 2617, 'OuterPostcode': 'N/A'...   [{'RollingCount': 1, 'OuterPostcode': 'AS11', ...
```

and I'm not sure how to seperate each column into its own dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to unpack it by specifying the dataset argument into normalise

like

```py
dfs = pd.json_normalize(data, 'data')
```

which gave me a nice dataset